# how to remove SF Visual Search banners by superfish.com

Tags: google-chrome-extension, spam, superfish, banner-ads, spam-prevention

I have some boring SF_VISUAL_SEARCH (by superfish.com) banners into my Google Chrome. They only appear in e-shops offering similar products to those that I'm looking at.
No estensions and no software installed. Maybe some other extensions have the superfish banners's call. How to remove them?

Comment: Check all of your installed extensions. Ad companies such as Superfish like to send mails to extension developers of popular extensions offering money in exchange for inserting ad code in their extension. You can find the installed extensions in your [user data directory](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory). Search each directory for malicious content. If you prefer a GUI for viewing the source code of extensions, take a look at [CRX Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin)

Comment: Thank you @RobW.
I found file sf.js installed into Google Chrome Extensions's folder **C:\Users\*USER*\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions**

There are so many folder with cripted name like **goanabmlmgfinmjohhepcpffcnkeobjm**

Inside one of them i found the superfish files. Search for js/sf.js and delete all the parent folder.

Comment: The extension that has installed all the SF_VISUAL_SEARCH banner was Translate selection Chrome's Extension

Comment: For me the rogue extension was the Pinterest Button. Didn't find it from the Chrome market anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a console (F12 or CTRL+SHIFT+J) into a simple page (that is not chrome store or start page). Go in the network tab of the console and start disabling extensions one by one then refresh the page where you have the console opened.